# Different QM and MM gradients in geometry optimization

Tags: geometry-optimization, openmm

I calculated the single point energy of some small molecule using the PM7 method (with COSMO solvation model) in MOPAC and calculated the gradients. Then I calculated MM potential energy with gradients (amber14sb force field and OBC2 implicit solvent) using the OpenMM program.

I expected the gradients to be different in value due to the differences in the methods, but the gradients also differ in direction, and finding a pair of co-directional gradients is quite difficult. I wanted to try taking the gradients from different calculations and inserting them into the BFGS optimization algorithm, but due to this difference in directions I get strange results.

How does this result correspond to practice? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Different methods will have different gradients, even comparing QM to QM or MM to MM. While some of them could potentially have co-directional gradients for a given geometry, in general the minima for different methods will be different.

Comment: @Tyberius is absolutely correct. Just to make it extra clear, imagine you separately optimised the geometry for the two methods to get the "zero force" structure for each method. Now create a new structure with all atoms exactly halfway between these two configurations; the atomic forces for this structure will be in almost exactly opposite directions between the two methods!